# NPM on Windows doesn't know the directory

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm in a subfolder `(D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project)`, but even in that directory, running `npm list` says that there's no such project in `D:\Alex\Desktop`.  I also can't install `node_modules` because none of the `npm` commands know the actual folder I'm in.  I haven't run into this issue at all before, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested Info to Gather (and add to your post):

1. What version of Windows is installed (likely not the issue, but there are some known issues associated with `Windows 7`)?
2. What version of `Node.js` is installed (Use: `node -v` to check)?
3. What version of `NPM` is installed (Use: `npm -v` to check)?

---

When `Node.js` is installed using the `Microsoft Windows installer package (.msi)` download, `NPM` will also be installed, but the version lags behind the latest. So, for example, if you install the current LTS version of `Node.js` (6.11.3), `NPM` will be at version: 3.10.10, whereas the latest version of `NPM` is: 5.4.2.

Based upon your description of the problem, I am guessing that your version of `Node.js` is current (or fairly close), but that your version of `NPM` may be a bit out of date. Older versions of `NPM` would commonly generate a confusing and misleading error message associated with local modules that did not contain a `package.json` file; so running `npm ls` would produce error output similar to:

```
npm ERR! error in D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

If I have guessed correctly, you should be able to resolve the problem by creating a `package.json` file in the `D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project` directory using one of the following options:

1. Open a command prompt terminal window in the: `D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project` directory/folder, run: `npm init`, and provide answers to the question prompts.
2. Open a command prompt terminal window in the: `D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project` directory/folder and run: `npm init --yes` (which will suppress the prompts and apply default values).
3. Use a text editor to paste the following drop-in values into: `D:\Alex\Desktop\Git\project\package.json`, which declares the 2 required values: `"name"`, `"version"`, and includes a `"description"` because if there is no `"description"` field in the `package.json`, `NPM` uses the first line of the `README.md` or `README` (and your project may not include either):

   ```
   {
     "name": "my-desktop-git-project",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "Alex's Desktop Git Project"
   }
   ```